# Mysqlfailover command - No slave is listed in health status

Tags: mysql, replication, failover

I have successfully created replication using `GTID_MODE`. It works perfectly. Now I need to setup automatic failover feature in it. I have run the following command.

```
mysqlfailover --master=root:abc@10.24.184.12:3306 --discover-slaves-login=root:abc
```

I have got the following results. No slave is listed.

```
MySQL Replication Failover Utility
Failover Mode = auto     Next Interval = Tue May

Master Information
------------------
Binary Log File   Position  Binlog_Do_DB  Binlog
mysql-bin.000016  9568

GTID Executed Set
8fe8b710-cd34-11e4-824d-fa163e52e544:1-1143

Replication Health Status
0 Rows Found.
Q-quit R-refresh H-health G-GTID Lists U-UUIDs U
```

But when I execute the `mysqlrplcheck` and `mysqlrplshow` commands, the slave is listed.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this is to give slave details also:

```
mysqlfailover --master=root:abc@10.24.184.12:3306 --discover-slaves-login=root:abc --slaves=root:abc@<host>, root:abc@<host>
```

where  is IP or hostname of slaves.